# Can I be refused a job because they don't have the uniform in the male version

Tags: job-search, discrimination, legal

There is a cashier position in a local supermarket, but they've said that for the moment they have no male uniforms and that I should try again in the future! The uniform is in my opinion fairly unisex; trousers as opposed to a skirt, plain blouse (which looks like a shirt) and a cardigan. I have no problem wearing this uniform and need the job. I'm fairly slight of build, so don't think sizing should be a problem. How do I stand on this?

Comment: Any useful answer would depend on your location.

Comment: Thought this was a duplicate of [How can I tell my boss the required uniform makes me personally uncomfortable?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/18280/how-can-i-tell-my-boss-the-required-uniform-makes-me-personally-uncomfortable) however on closer reading seems to be the exact opposite take.

Comment: Depends what country you're in. Illegal in the UK/EU.

Comment: Voted to close: this is not a clear-cut case and you'd be better served with professional legal advice or, failing that, the [Law SE](http://law.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 12):

This is a borderline legal issue.  In the US, you can not be turned down for a job based on your sex.  They are turning you down because you are a male.  Not having a male uniform is their issue, not yours.  *In my opinion*, that sounds like sex discrimination.

You should consult a lawyer in your jurisdiction, *if* you feel the position is worth fighting for.  However, lawyers/courts do cost money and there is no guarantee of a positive outcome.  And do you really want to work at a place you took to court?

Comment: A cheaper solution is if you have evidence that this is the case a trade union would be interested

Comment: Difficult legal question. As described, it's not the gender that's the problem, but the lack of uniforms. No idea what a judge or a jury would think about it. Now if the problem is that they have never designed a male version of that uniform and will for the foreseeable future not be able to supply one, that would a strong argument against them.

Comment: @gnasher729 It is a gender issue. They claim they are not able to hire a male. That is a gender issue. But as noted above, this is a case for lawyers.